# Filter mat-table on button click condition

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a mat-table that I want to filter to display rows in the table that have a weight greater than 10. Any advice on how to accomplish this?

Please see my stackblitz here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4ttand?file=src/app/table-basic-flex-example.ts

Comment: Could you share your stackblitz code url?  The shared url is the output of your code.

Comment: Updated stackblitz!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
filterTable() {
        // logic here to filter table showing only rows that have a weight > 10
        this.dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA.filter(df => df.weight > 10)
      }
```

Comment: Awesome - this worked well!

Comment: I am using this on dynamic data and get ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined. How to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

I have added the logic for your use-case. Kindly check it out.

```
filterTable() {
    // logic here to filter table showing only rows that have a weight > 10
    this.dataSource = this.dataSource.filter((item) => { 
         console.log(Math.floor(item.weight));
         return Math.floor(item.weight) > 10});
         console.log('***********', this.dataSource);
}
```

Comment: Awesome - this worked well!